# Realm Java - Using raw sql

Tags: realm

I was searching the forum for a way to use a raw query in the realm database, but the examples in the forum doesn't exist or don't work.

Can anyone explain me how can I use a raw sql query on a Realm database?

Thanks for the help

Comment: As far as I know realm is not SQL based aka as a NoSQL Database and [realm java](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1573) does not seem to implement string based queries, at least it's still marked as open feature request. So if you want this, you probably need a query-builder or another idea and it depends on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Realm is not an ORM, it has its own native core. It is not based on SQLite. It is NoSQL. It does not support SQL queries. But you can see how queries work in the official documentation: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#queries

Answer (score 2):

Realm is not based on SQLite. It is an Object Store or Graph database. This means that SQL queries doesn't really make sense, since e.g JOIN's doesn't exist at all.  So no, that isn't possible. All queries are created using `realm.where()` and similar methods.